# sObject - converting plural to singular?

Tags: apex

Is there a way to retrieve the singular object API name from its plural (or vice-versa)?

```
SObject record;
//system.debug(record) = MyObject__c:{Id=...}
String parts[] = (MyObjects__r, id);
while(parts.size() > 1) {
    temp = temp.getSObject(parts.remove(0)); // error "Invalid relationship MyObjects__r for MyObject__c"
}
```

Comment: We don't have enough code to help you. There are several ways to get the API name for the child record, depending on what you need to do.

Comment: Guess I was looking for a method (prebuilt - but I guess there isn't any) that would take (one of (for example) 'opportunities', 'leads', 'cases', 'accounts', and return (respectively) 'opportunity', 'lead', 'case', 'account'.  Not really a child relationship, per se.

Comment: I'm using a (completely not bulletproof) work-around now to replace ending 'ies' with 'y', 's', with '', and '__r' with '__c' - was hoping for something more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You can always identify what objects are related with the `Schema` class. I think in your case you want to use [`getChildRelationships`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Schema_ChildRelationship.htm#apex_class_Schema_ChildRelationship) to grab metadata about a relationship.

```java
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
List<Schema.ChildRelationship> c = r.getChildRelationships();
Map<String, String> relationshipNameToSObject = new Map<String, String>();
for(Schema.ChildRelationship cr : c) {
    relationshipNameToSObject.put(
        cr.getRelationshipName(), 
        cr.getChildSObject().getDescribe().getName()
    );
}
```

The above code will create a map of relationship name to related object name (e.g. MyObjects__r --> Some_Object__c).