# struggling with getSObject / get syntax

Tags: apex, compile-error

Given the following output for JSON.serializePretty(record) :

```
{
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Work_Order_Product__c",
    "url" : "/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/Work_Order_Product__c/a0c750000000aVmAAI"
  },
  "Work_Order__c" : "a0675000000ELPfAAO",
  "Id" : "a0c750000000aVmAAI",
  "Product__c" : "01ta00000040BcjAAE",
  "Product__r" : {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Product2",
      "url" : "/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/Product2/01ta00000040BcjAAE"
    },
    "Name" : "Widget",
    "Id" : "01ta00000040BcjAAE"
  }
}
```

.. how do I retrieve the value from "Name" (Widget), above?  All my combos of getSObject and get seem to fail.

EDIT: Code, as requested:

Note, I *expect* most results to fail (and return null thanks to the catch block) - problem is, the record I'm expecting success.. yep - also returns null).  Here she is :

```
private Object getValue(List<SObject> records, String path) { //Work_Order_Products__r.Product__r.Name
    for(sObject record : records) {
        SObject temp = record;
        String[] parts = path.split('\\.');
        try {
            while(parts.size() > 1) {
                temp = temp.getSObject(parts.remove(0));
            }
            return temp.get(parts[0]);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thank you kindly

Comment: Seeing the code you've tried so far would be helpful (along with any error messages you're getting), though I do have an educated guess. SObject's `.get()` method returns an `Object`, which is nearly useless on its own. You really need to do an explicit type-cast to make the result useful (so like `String name = (String)rec.get('Name');`)

Comment: if you deserialize into a `Work_Order_Product__c` object you can access the fields using dot notation - like `myWorkProduct.Name`

Comment: Might be similar to [this issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/178400/2995).

Comment: Are you sure the o/p is from the same record you're trying to access. Few of the records might not have `relationship` field populated & so they'll always return `null`. It is similar to `contact.Account.Name` when `contact.AccountId is null`.

Answer (score 0):

My struggle turned out to be related to an earlier question of mine: [sObject - converting plural to singular?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/367845)

By converting my objNames to their singular variety, I was able to pluck the targeted fields - thanks!